# How to import java library in scala using sbt

Tags: java, scala, import, sbt

I am working on a small project. I downloaded a java library and packaged it using sbt. I created a lib folder under the root folder and placed the newly packaged jar in that lib folder. Now I am having trouble importing it. The package name of the library is "com.cd.reddit". How do I import the java library in my scala program? I used the

```
show unmanagedJars
```

command and it appeared, so it is in the class path.

Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks.

Here is my build.sbt:

```
name := "RedditBot"

version := "1.0"

mainClass := Some("reddit.bot.core.Main")

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.3.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "0.3.15"

libraryDependencies += "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-mapper-asl" % "1.9.13"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.1"

libraryDependencies += "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "uk.co.bigbeeconsultants" %% "bee-client" % "0.21.+",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.+",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core"    % "1.0.+",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.+"
)

resolvers += "Big Bee Consultants" at "http://repo.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/repo"
```

Here is the errors I am getting when I try to import the library

```
[error] /home/lamez/GitHub/RedditBot/src/main/scala/reddit/bot/core/Main.scala:6: object cd is not a member of package com
[error] import com.cd.reddit.Reddit
[error]            ^
[error] /home/lamez/GitHub/RedditBot/src/main/scala/reddit/bot/core/Main.scala:8: object cd is not a member of package com
[error] import com.cd.reddit.json.mapping.RedditJsonMessage
[error]            ^
[error] /home/lamez/GitHub/RedditBot/src/main/scala/reddit/bot/core/Main.scala:9: object cd is not a member of package com
[error] import com.cd.reddit.json.util.RedditComments
```

Comment: Try doing the following. Run `sbt console` and then import the Java package as `import com.cd.reddit`. See if this works or not ?

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that I have already tried that. No luck.

Comment: can you share the contents of your build.sbt ?

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta, I added the build.sbt to the post.

Comment: What is the actual error that you are seeing, when you try to import the class, can you add your main class ?

Comment: @ipiepiora I added the errors that I am getting, also I the main class has nothing in it at the moment.

Comment: @lpiepiora, I misspelled your name in my last comment, sorry. I added the errors as requested. Also there isn't anything in the main class, just trying to get the imports correct.

Comment: If you list the contents of your jar, like `jar tf lib/RedditLib.jar`, do you actually see those alleged classes, like `com/cd/reddit/Reddit.class`?

Comment: @0__ I did as you asked and it only show the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Then there's your problem - the class is not really in the jar :)

Comment: Yeah, I have come to realize that. So why didn't sbt package the classes? Did I do something wrong? I did: sbt clean package.

Comment: @JamesLittle clearly there is a problem with the other project that builds the jar. Hard to say if you did something wrong without seeing the other project's setup. Can you attach anything of relevance. Better yet a minimal complete example reproducing the issue.